# 404 - File Not Found - Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\ci4app::home

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter-4

Codeigniter 4 installed in sub-folder

CI seems to be looking at the sub-folder to use as the controller (using auto route - ie no routes), I even set up a route to try to direct the url to the correct controller but it still looks at the wrong url segment https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#uri-segments

Ex: mywebsite.com/ci4app/home/participantlogin

`Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Ci4app::home`

CI thinks "ci4app" is the controller, it is really "home", it seems like I should just update a baseurl somewhere

Messed with .env, config file, .htaccess and apache config.

Folder Structure:

/var/www/html/ - WordPress Site

/var/www/html/myapp - CI4

Comment: Show the code of the controller and your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the baseURL is set correctly. The sub-directory must appear in the baseURL (in .env file or app/Config/App.php). For example if CI is in a directory called ci4app, then the baseURL should be http://urltoserver/ci4app/

For .htaccess modifications, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/misterzik/a86bb75ba8a0d6edd18d) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check for CamelCase spellings... home should be Home <-- Notice Capital "H"

You also have a Capital "C"

```php
\App\Controllers\Ci4app::Home
```

This should match exactly what you have in your controller, Example:

```php
class Home extends BaseController
```

In your case it should look like this:

```php
\App\Controllers\Home::ParticipantLogin
```

And check your Route as well to ensure it is going to the right place:

```php
// Routes.php
$routes->get('ci4app', '\App\Controllers\Home::ParticipantLogin');
```

When someone types in domain.com/ci4app it will route internally to home Controller -> ParticipantLogin Method

Good Luck, Happy Coding!